# Disable editor tabs duplication while opening a single file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, editor, settings

I have this problem bugging me for a little while now and I didn't find any help on SO or other resources.

In Eclipse Java EE (Version: Indigo Service Release 2  Build id: 20120216-1857), when double clicking a file (a class, or XML or whatever else) in the Package Explorer to open it in the editor, it will open a new tab every time I double click the file, even though the file has been previously opened in another tab. So for example, double clicking 3 times in a row on a single file in the Package Explorer will open 3 tabs in the editor for this single file.

I found some info about how to display search result in a common tab, or how to open a single file in two different editors, but nothing about this problem, I cannot find any setting to disable this annoying behavior.

Anyone got some clues about this problem ?

Comment: I had this MDI tabsplosion problem with CMake's Eclipse project generator, which makes files appear in multiple places (per-target virtual folders).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After putting back the default settings of Eclipse, it seems to be alright now. I will update this post in case the same problem happens later on.